# Соединение циклов for

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Мне нужно сделать цикл `for` таким образом: от 1 до 3 и от 6 до 9. Как это сделать? Я могу только отдельно

```
for(i=1; i=3; i++)
...
for(i=6; i=9; i++)
...
```

Можно ли их как-то соединить?

Comment: т.е пропустить 4,5,6? или как?

Comment: да, именно

Answer (score 8):

Первый способ: пропускать итерации

```
for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    if (4 <= i && i <= 5)
        continue;
    // do something
}
```

Второй способ: делать "перескок" во время изменения шага. (тернарный оператор)

```
for (i = 1; i <= 9; i = (i == 3) ? 6 : (i + 1)) {
    // do something
}
```

**UPD:** Как тут уже заметили, у вас код неправильно написан.

for (начальные значения; условие при котором работает цикл; задание изменения переменных)

**UPD2:** как работает тернарный оператор:

```
A=(B)?C:D;
```

Если условие B истинно, то в переменную A записывается значение C, иначе туда записывается значение D.

Comment: можно объяснить второй способ
как он перескакивает?

Comment: @GALIAF95, в правой части for(;;) изменяется i на значение *тернарного оператора* (i==3)? 6: (i+1). 

Т.е. если i равно 3, то присвоим i 6 (сделаем Ваш "перескок"), иначе увеличим i на 1.

Comment: ПОНЯЛ СПАСИБО

Answer (score 6):

Как всегда выкладываю оригинальный способ без ветвлений:

```
for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
{
    i+=(i==4)*2;
    ...
}
```

Самый оригинальный способ:

```
for(int i=1; i<10; i+=1+(i==4)*2)
    ...
```

Не оригинальный, но более понятный способ:

```
for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
{
    if(i==4) i=6;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

как-то так

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    if (i = >4 && i <= 6) {
        printf("Ничего не делаем");
    }
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Comment: @johniek_comp, в C++ (C) **нет операции =>** !!!

А те кто плюсует - вы текст читаете ?

Comment: я крестов не знаю, я примерно написал, если человек (ТС) думает то он перепишет под свой язык я думаю...тут главное толкнуть

Comment: @johniek_comp, IMHO ХэшКод будет категорически не согласен с таким подходом к **ответам**.